# Executing Commands in multiple devices using Python Code in Putty/Plink

Tags: python-3.x, putty

I am trying to execute commands that are in a file and respective host credentials in another file, the target is to pull list of commands from that file and execute the commands in the hosts which are in the Credential file.

The outputs should be routed to another file, I tried to write a code and I was able to achieve on for one device and one command. The output is printing in the screen but with /n for every line not as the desired output.

For now I had placed the command in the same file but my target was to pull the commands in line procedure, Like first line execute the command after that execute the next command.

Please help me in resolving this, I am trying to write it in python.

```
HOST_CRED.txt:

Hostname <IP> <USERID> <PASSWORD> <command>


import socket
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
with open("HOST_CRED.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        x=line.split()
        cmd='plink.exe -ssh '+ x[2] + '@'+ x[1] + ' -pw ' + x[3] + ' ' + x[4]
        p=Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
        output=p.stdout.read()
        print(output)
```

Comment: Do not run an external console application to implemnent SSH. Use a native Python SSH library, like Paramiko.

Comment: Thanks for the response what about the other piece i tired something different and used another code, but the issue is how to i run the same command in multiple hosts not sure how to achieve. i would also like to know how to use the Paramiko.

Comment: Other Code that worked but does only for one host and one command need the same thing to do multiple host and multiple commands.

from subprocess import *
with open("output.txt", 'w') as output:
 with open("outputerror.txt", 'w') as outerror:
  with open("EMC_HOST_CRED.txt") as f:
   for prim in f:
    with open("command.txt") as g:
     for sec in g:
      x=prim.split()
      y=sec.split()
      print(x)
      print(y)
      cmd='plink.exe -ssh '+ x[2] + '@'+ x[1] + ' -pw ' + x[3] + ' ' + y[0]
      call(cmd, stdout=output, stderr=outerror)